# blackberry device debugging on os x loses access to file system

Tags: macos, debugging, blackberry, filesystems, jde

It's great that I can develop Blackberry software on OS X. I need to run the desktop software to gain access to the device from the JDE. When I start a debug session I can't set breakpoints, but I can see System.out on the JDE console. Problem is that the phone can't see file:///store/... (error 10003) Research shows that as long as desktop is connected the phone then the running application doesn't have access to the file system. Disconnecting phone from finder doesn't help. Disconnecting blackberry desktop terminates the debug session.

So, the question: how can I keep the JDE debugger connected with an application that reads and writes files on the phone?

Answer (score 0):

1. plug in the blackberry via USB
2. Blackberry desktop will pop up
3. Run JDE
4. Send mac to sleep
5. Leave blackberry plugged in
6. Wake up Mac again
7. No drives reconnect
8. Blackberry desktop running but shows ejected
9. JDE can still see BlackBerry
10. Debugging works while application can see Blackberry file-system

Comment: Nice tip. It's BlackBerry :) I'm coding and as much as possible work in IntelliJ IDEA and doing final run and test in eclipse :) In our team we usually install windows to develop for BB